# Current system time on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, time

Is it posible in code to check on iPhone/iPad if the system time is automatic (NITZ from carrier, NTP or GPS set by OS) or set manually by user?

Comment: Yes, normal user changing system time, without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 1):

I would connect to ntp.apple.com and compare the system time with the result I get back.

Check out the [ios-ntp](http://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/) project for accessing NTP in Obj-C

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there also way without requiring network / http? I mean, I dont need correct time, just information if the time is manually set by user OR retreived from carrier.